# shortcode on non wordpress php file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to display a wordpress' plugin output with shortcode through do_shortcode().

It's gonna be displayed inside tooltip and the only way to call it, is by requesting a php file through ajax.

So I have a blank page called weather.php with the shortcode inside. Ofcourse it won't work like this since it's a non-wordpress file.

My question is.. what I have to insert in that file to make do_shortcode() work?

In other words.. wordpressize this page!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code at the top of the weather.php file

```
include_once("ADJUST/PATH/wp-load.php");
```

The wp-load.php file is found in the main directory of your WordPress installation.

Comment: sweet! it worked but with single quotes instead of double!

and only with absolute path :/

rly thanks though!

Comment: `include_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp/wp-load.php");`

there we go :D